# Change App Visual State in WinRT by Code

Tags: windows-runtime

Is it possible to change the visual state of a page (actually the whole app) through code? 
For example, I accessed a page that would appear only in Snapped mode and on this page I have a back button to go to the previous page but I would like also to change the Visual state to Fullscreen. Can this be achieved?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. The shell configuration is off limits to applications. It can enter snapped view as a result of user action.

Comment: One exception is that an application can call `TryUnsnap` to request a switch to fullscreen, but the request can be denied.

Comment: Who can deny [TryUnsnap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryunsnap)? The docs say "This call will only succeed when the app is running in the foreground".

Comment: I think you just answered your own question.

Comment: So first, that would mean my answer is actually wrong and then what it says would mean that if the app is in snapped view and it is visible - it can go to full-screen view. Though it doesn't say anything about the snapped view - I assume it would work for snapped view as well?

Comment: I have found a Snap Sample among the sample provided by Microsoft, and solved my problem with a TryUnsnap. Altough, after many snaps and unsnaps, when the TryUnsnap is called the app seems to have crashed but it recovers after several seconds... Odd.